# Excel: error in IF(D2>B2 AND (F2==auc OR F2==r2), D2-B2, B2-D2)

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is wrong in my formula:

```
=IF(D2>B2 AND (F2==auc OR F2==r2), D2-B2, B2-D2)
```

`auc` and `r2` are values in column `F2`.
I want the following logic:

if value in col `D` > val in col `B` AND metric is `auc` or `r2` then `D-B`, else `B-D`

Now sure what is not correct in my expression.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing it incorrectly. It should be:

```
=IF(AND(D2>B2, OR(F2="auc", F2="r2")), D2-B2, B2-D2)
```

In Excel, the functions' arguments are inside the parenthesis. Also you don't use `==` but `=`.

[image]

Comment: damn my pythonic urge, thank you